# Why is this $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $ bundle trivial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups

Please tell me why the following example of a principal $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-bundle over an affine ring is trivial.  Let $ \{x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\} $ a basis of $ \mathbf{V}^{\ast} $, $ c_{1}(t),c_{2}(t) $ two non-zero, linearly independent, additive polynomials such that the only common root is zero, and $ \beta: \mathbb{G}_{a} \to \operatorname{GL}(\mathbf{V}) $ be the representation whose co-action is the following one:
\begin{align*}
\beta^{\sharp}(x_{1}) &= x_{1} \\
\beta^{\sharp}(x_{2}) &= x_{2} \\
\beta^{\sharp}(x_{3}) &= x_{3}+c_{2}(t)x_{2}+c_{1}(t)x_{1}.
\end{align*}
The stabilizer of any closed point $ y \in D(x_{1}x_{2}) $ is equal to $ 0 $.  Therefore $ D(x_{1}x_{2}) $ is a principal $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-bundle over its image in $ \operatorname{Spec}(k[x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}]^{\mathbb{G}_{a}}) $.  By a theorem of Demazure, Gabriel, and others it is a trivial $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-bundle.

If a variety $ X $ is a trivial $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-bundle over $ Y $, then there is clearly a separable $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-equivariant map from $ X $ to $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $.  If there is a separable $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-equivariant map $ \phi: X \to \mathbb{G}_{a} $, then let $ Y $ be the fibre over $ 0 $.  There is an isomorphism $ \psi: \mathbb{G}_{a} \times Y \to X $ which sends $ (t,y) $ to $ t \ast y $.  The inverse to $ \psi $ is the map which sends $ x $ to $ \left(\phi(x), \left(-\phi(x)\right) \ast x\right) $.  This shows that a variety $ X $ is a trivial $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-bundle over $ X//\mathbb{G}_{a} $ if and only if there is a separable, $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-equivariant morphism $ \phi: X \to \mathbb{G}_{a} $.

If $ D(x_{1}x_{2}) $ is a trivial $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-bundle over $ \operatorname{Spec}(k[x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}]_{x_{1}x_{2}}^{\mathbb{G}_{a}}) \cong \operatorname{Spec}(k[x_{1},x_{2}]_{x_{1}x_{2}}) $, then there is a $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-equivariant morphism $ \phi: D(x_{1}x_{2}) \to \mathbb{G}_{a} $.

If $ \Delta_{\mathbb{G}_{a}}: \mathbb{G}_{a} \times \mathbb{G}_{a} \to \mathbb{G}_{a} $ is the multiplication morphism of $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $, then the existence of the morphism $ \phi $ means that
\begin{equation*}
\Delta_{\mathbb{G}_{a}} \circ (\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{G}_{a}}, \phi) = \phi \circ \beta
\end{equation*}
A consequence of this is that if $ \phi^{\sharp}(t) = g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e} $, then
\begin{align*}
\beta^{\sharp}(g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e}) &= \beta^{\sharp} \circ \phi^{\sharp}(t) \\
&= (\operatorname{id}_{k[t]} \otimes \phi^{\sharp}) \circ \Delta^{\sharp}(t) \\
&= (\operatorname{id}_{k[t]} \otimes \phi^{\sharp})(t \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes t) \\
&= t+g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e}
\end{align*}
Assume that $ g(X) = \sum_{j=0}^{d} x_{3}^{j} g_{j}(x_{1},x_{2}) $.  Since
\begin{align*}
\beta^{\sharp}(g(X)-g_{0}(x_{1},x_{2})) &= \beta^{\sharp}(g(X))-g_{0}(x_{1},x_{2}) \\
&= g(X)+t(x_{1}x_{2})^{e}-g_{0}(x_{1},x_{2}) \\
&= g(X)-g_{0}(x_{1},x_{2})+t(x_{1}x_{2})^{e}
\end{align*}
the pair of polynomials $ (g(X)-g_{0}(x_{1},x_{2}),(x_{1}x_{2})^{e}) $ has the same property as the pair $ (g(X),(x_{1}x_{2})^{e}) $.  As a result, we may assume for the next part that $ x_{3} $ divides $ g(X) $.  Because $ c_{1}(t),c_{2}(t) $ are additive polynomials, the following identities hold:
\begin{multline*}
\beta^{\sharp}\left( x_{3}+c_{2}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e})x_{2}+c_{1}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e})x_{1} \right) \\
= \beta^{\sharp}(x_{3})+c_{2}(\beta^{\sharp}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e}))x_{2}+c_{1}(\beta^{\sharp}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e}))x_{1} \\
= x_{3}+c_{2}(t)x_{2}+c_{1}(t)x_{1}+c_{2}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e}-t)x_{2}+c_{1}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e}-t)x_{1} \\
= x_{3}+(c_{2}(t)-c_{2}(t))x_{2}+(c_{1}(t)-c_{1}(t))x_{1}+c_{2}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e})x_{2}+c_{1}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e})x_{1} \\
=x_{3}+c_{2}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e})x_{2}+c_{1}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e})x_{1}.
\end{multline*}
This shows that if $ \beta^{\sharp}(g(X)) = g(X)+t(x_{1}x_{2})^{e} $, then $ x_{3}+c_{2}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e})x_{2}+c_{1}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e})x_{1} $ is an invariant rational function.  However, by our assumption that $ x_{3} $ divides $ g(X) $, we know that
\begin{align*}
x_{3} & \mid \left(x_{3}+c_{2}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e})x_{2}+c_{1}(-g(X)/(x_{1}x_{2})^{e})x_{1}\right)\\
& \in k[x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}]_{x_{1}x_{2}}^{\mathbb{G}_{a}} \\
& = k[x_{1},x_{2}]_{x_{1}x_{2}}.
\end{align*}
This is a contradiction.  What is the error here?

Comment: What is the statement of the "theorem of Demazure, Gabriel, and others"?

Comment: I have not yet been able to find a reference, but I believe the theorem states that a principal $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-bundle over an affine scheme is trivial.

Comment: Hi @PiotrAchinger, I asked for a reference of the theorem and got a proof.  The actual theorem is that a $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-torsor in the $ \operatorname{fppf} $ topology over an affine scheme is a trivial $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-bundle.  David Benjamin Lim gave a proof here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392572/a-principal-mathbbg-a-bundle-over-an-affine-variety-is-trivial/392574?noredirect=1#comment1001815_392574

Comment: Ok, this is what I suspected. Then I guess your problem is that the base is not affine, only quasi-affine. For example, $X={\rm SL}_2/U \simeq \mathbf{A}^2\setminus \{0\}$ has infinite-dimensional $H^1(\mathcal{O})$, and has plenty of nontrivial $\mathbf{G}_a$-torsors, ${\rm SL}_2\to {\rm SL}_2/U$ being one of them.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I believe that the base is affine since it is $ \operatorname{Spec}(k[x_{1},x_{2}]_{x_{1}x_{2}}) $.  I think I may have found the problem, and I am about to post an answer.  Let me know if you think it is a good one.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Also, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I think the error is that the action is not free: $t$ stabilizes $(-c_2(t), c_1(t), 1)$, and for $t$ generic this is a point of $D(x_1x_2)$. Or am I missing something (again)?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I believe that the action is free.  If the only common root of $ c_{2}(t) $ and $ c_{1}(t) $ is zero, then for an arbitrary point $ (y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}) $ to be stabilized $ c_{1}(t) $ and $ c_{2}(t) $ must equal zero.  This means that $ t $ must equal zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124193/discussion-between-piotr-achinger-and-schemer).

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the problem with the argument is in the statement that $ D(x_{1}x_{2}) $ is a principal $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-bundle over $ \operatorname{Spec}(k[x_{1},x_{2}]_{x_{1}x_{2}}) $.  In order for $ D(x_{1}x_{2}) $ to be a principal $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-bundle, it must be locally trivial.  If I am correct, this $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-space is nowhere trivial unless one of $ c_{1}(t) $ or $ c_{2}(t) $ is equal to zero and the other is equal to $ t $.  Namely, there is no open sub-variety of $ D(x_{1}x_{2}) $ which is a trivial $ \mathbb{G}_{a} $-bundle over its image in $ \operatorname{Spec}(k[x_{1},x_{2}]_{x_{1}x_{2}}) $. Therefore, the theorem does not apply.